# Crontab is not auto-restarting service

Tags: cron

I am trying to auto restart smokeping every five minutes using crontab (for a specific test), but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
> sudo crontab -e
 ...

#Restart smokeping every five minutes
*/5 * * * * service smokeping restart
```

What am I doing wrong? There is no information on syslog.

Comment: Try giving the full paths `/usr/sbin/service` and `/sbin/restart` - cron's default environment is very limited, in particular it only has `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` iirc

Comment: It worked after I followed your advice and also followed this guide http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html please write an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is not working is that cron's default `PATH` is hardcoded and it looks like that:

```
#ifndef _PATH_DEFPATH
# define _PATH_DEFPATH "/usr/bin:/bin"
#endif
```

https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/blob/52bacc70b592d354efff8231375bf2d51bd4ef52/pathnames.h#L77

More specifically, the `service` command cannot be found.
If you try executing `which service` you will get something like:
`/usr/sbin/service`
This is why it may be helpful to explicitly set the `PATH` variable in your crontab.

A full crontab example follows:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

*/5 * * * * service smokeping restart
```